# jquery animation not working correctly

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have a navigation bar and a trigger with the same class and my thought is that when the trigger is hovered, jquery will send into animation the moving of both the trigger and the nav bar which is hidden through overflow on the bottom of the page.

I got the jquery animate, but my problem is that when I hover over the trigger and then move to the navigation bar with the same class, it sends into motion the hiding of the bar again instead of staying open because I'm hovering over it.  I'm not sure how to get both the trigger and nav bar to stay still once open until I'm not hovering over either item.

Here's the basics (operating in wordpress that's why jQuery over $):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.nav').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.nav').animate({
            bottom: "0px"
        }, 1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.nav').animate({
            bottom: "-40px"
        }, 1500);
    });        
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav nav-trigger" id="nav-trigger"><a href="#">Navigate</a></div>
<div class="nav" id="nav-bar"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {position:absolute; bottom:-40px;}
.nav-trigger {margin-left:50%; left:-100px;}
#nav-trigger {height:80px; width:200px; background:#bd265e; color:#fff;}
#nav-bar {height:40px; width:100%; background:#bd265e; color:#fff; text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Add a class `inanimation` and before hiding it, check if it is in animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `.nav` elements. When you hover over the first one, it slides up, and your mouse moves from the first to the second `.nav`, triggering a slide down and another slide up, etc. etc.

The simplest solution is to `.stop` all animations before you start a new one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.nav').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.nav').stop().animate({
            bottom: "0px"
        }, 1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.nav').stop().animate({
            bottom: "-40px"
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LwyAB/

Comment: This works great in jfiddle but when I implement it into the site i get the same issue. It only stays put when on a link and the second I unhover a link it starts the downward animation. It's like it's not using the full nav bar as a selector but rather just it's content. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your selectors aren't correct. I can't really say from here.

Comment: Just to test, I took out any content on the .nav divs and they won't move at all without content in them. Now I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with CSS!

http://jsfiddle.net/a7nM3/

Put everything inside a wrapper for the hover

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav nav-trigger" id="nav-trigger"><a href="#">Navigate</a></div>
    <div class="nav" id="nav-bar"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
</div>
```

And then some transitions

```
body
{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px;
    width: 100%;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper:hover
{
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: It's generally preferable to post your solution in your answer as well as in a working fiddle.